# Loading .csv file with UTF-8 encoding error "no lines available in input" - byte order mark (BOM) "ï.."

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I am loading a CSV file using `read.csv2()` function. The file has non-ASCII characters like "é".
When loading it in Excel, they display correctly with UTF-8 encoding so I am guessing I need to use the same encoding when loading this file with `read.csv2()`.

But everything went wrong...

```
# works but non-ASCII characters do not display correctly
read.csv2(file = "./data/myfile.csv") 
read.csv2(file = "./data/myfile.csv", fileEncoding = "latin1")

# does not work: error "no lines available in input"
read.csv2(file = "./data/myfile.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

I have tried to use `read.delim()` and `read.table()` with no success; I got the same error. Note that `headers`, `sep` and `quotes` seems to be ok as the table displays correctly when using `read.csv2(file = "./data/myfile.csv")` (except non-ASCII characters...).

I do not know hot to make it reproducible... If you have any tip do not hesitate to comment!

---

EDIT
When I look at the 1st header of the 1st column, it shows a strange `ï..` in front of the name of the column. But when I open it in Excel, there is nothing (not even a space) in front of this line header...

Comment: First thing: try to find out the encoding of the file, without guessing. How the file was generated? Else: could you open in a text editor, and change the encoding, until you see one which seems correct. (but this may fail, for similar encodings, maybe wikipedia could help you, by adding additional characters, to discriminate better). Only after this, you can check the rest.

Comment: About your edit. You have the BOM. Check R, on how to ignore BOM (I think "utf-8-bom" or similar)

Comment: Excel likely uses a different encoding. Try to find which one your Excel is using. Other alternative: Go to RStudio -> File -> Save with encoding; it will show what the system default encoding is. Try using that encoding in `read.csv2` and see if it works.

Comment: On my machine, to read Excel csv files I use `encoding = "WINDOWS-1252"`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I think this is the problem, when I open it with text editor and use "save as", encoding is UTF-8 with BOM. I do not know how the file was generated, I downloaded it from public data. I'll try this and get back to you asap

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi you were right! Using `fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM"` solved the problem! I did not know about BOM... Many thanks! Feel free to post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the *usual* BOM problem. BOM is usually used to indicate the byte order on *generic* UTF-16 and UTF-32 (where byte order is relevant).

Obviously Microsoft think that changing interpretation of existing standard is the way to go (who care about interoperability to non-Microsoft systems?), so they use BOM as indication that the file is UTF-8, to distinguish from other legacy encodings used by DOS and Windows. (Note: Linux and Apple changed default encoding to UTF-8 without need to break stuffs, or adding BOM, and in a much quicker way).

So, UTF-8 files created by Microsoft usually have BOM (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF), which is shown as `ï»¿` on cp1252 (the Microsoft extension to Latin-1).

But most of tools (not made by Microsoft) misinterpret BOM, sometime following the standard, so interpreting it as hidden white space (the original meaning of the codepoint converted in most modern Unicode standard as BOM), or just seeing it as binary data, so just ignoring data.

For this reason, now we have the encoding `utf-8-bom`, which just skip the initial BOM (or create the BOM at writing). This usually fix the issue.